# Is the Klein bottle a quotient of a $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$-action on the plane?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, group-actions, klein-bottle

One of the basic examples of a group action on a topological space is the $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}-$action on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose quotient is a torus.

There is also an example of a $G-$action on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose quotient is a Klein bottle, but $G\neq\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, being instead the fundamental group of the Klein bottle.

My question is: is there a $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}-$action on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose quotient is a Klein bottle?

I understand that, if there is such an action, it can't be properly discontinuous, otherwise the Klein bottle would have fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: A better question might be: Suppose that $G$ is a countable group acting topologically and faithfully on a connected manifold $M$ with quotient homeomorphic to a manifold. Is the action properly discontinuous?

Comment: Some of the 17 wallpaper groups are countable, act topologically and faithfully on $\mathbb{R}^2$,  the action is not properly discontinuous, and their quotient is homeomorphic to a manifold $M$. However, in those cases, $M$ is not the Klein bottle.

Comment: These actions are properly discontinuous with the most common definition, just not free.

Comment: What's easy to see is that every isometric faithful $G$-action on a connected Riemannian manifold with Hausdorff quotient has to be properly discontinuous (i.e. for every compact subset $K$ there are only finitely many $g\in G$ such that $gK\cap K\ne \emptyset$.

Comment: Shouldn't be possible; after suitable isotopy you're asking to preserve orientation on one copy of $\mathbb{R}$ but flip it on the other.  Those lines are circles in the sphere, you can't change the orientation on only one.